# Как сделать кнопку, которая будет скролить вниз до следующего элемента сайта?

Tags: javascript, html, css

К примеру, первая часть сайта и на ней кнопка "Read more", нажимая на неё мне нужно что бы страница скролилась до следующей части сайта

Comment: Гуглите в яндексе "html якорь плавная прокрутка" и изучаете ссылки.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<html>
<head>
// Some code
</head>
<body>
 <a href='#about'>Read more</a>
  //Some code
  <div id='about'>
   <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...</p>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

у вас есть несколько вариантов:

1. через html-якоря (<a href="...")
2. программно: получаете елемент (document.getElement...), берете его offsetTop, потом document.documentElement.body.scrollTo({top: element.offsetTop})